# RichTextBox ignores keystrokes (Home,End,PgUp,PgDn) when IsReadOnly is true

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I have a WPF `RichTextBox` control that I want to behave like a normal `RichTextBox` in every way except that the user cannot edit the text and the caret is not visible. The issue I'm having is that when I change `IsReadOnly` to `False`, the `RichTextBox` stops reacting to keystrokes. I  want it to respond normally to keystrokes like Home, End, PgUp, PgDn, Up, Down. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.isreadonly.aspx) doesn't mention this behavior.

```
<RichTextBox
    IsReadOnly="True"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    Width="65" Height="20">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            Line 1
            Line 2
            Line 3
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

I've tried adding an `OnKeyDown` event handler, but it doesn't fire. I've watched the events in Snoop as I push keys with the `RichTextBox` in keyboard focus and no fired events are shown in Snoop. I've tried setting `IsDocumentEnabled` explicitly to `True`, but that also has no effect. I've tried wrapping the `RichTextBox` in a `ScrollViewer`, but this has no effect either.

Any suggestions for how I can maintain this `RichTextBox` as `IsReadOnly=True`, but get the expected keystroke behavior of a `RichTextBox`?

Comment: For a RichTextBox, you would use the PreviewKeyDown event handler and then check for the key pressed. I prefer the solution offered by @Meleak but here's a code example of how to do it manually: https://gist.github.com/1915136

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `IsReadOnlyCaretVisible` to True

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True"
             IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"
             ... />
```

If you don't want the caret to be visible then set the `CaretBrush` to `Transparent`

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True"
             IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"
             CaretBrush="Transparent"
             ... />
```